# How to prioritise certain output in MultiOutput LSTM Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, classification, lstm, multilabel-classification

Basically, I am creating an LSTM model with Tensorflow and the shape of my input data is something like

(10000 users, 6 timesteps, 20 feature columns) => (10000,6,20)

The model is doing a binary classification using LSTM with 20 output columns giving the shape of (10000, 20).

*PS. I'm not doing classification with 20 classes, I'm doing a classification that gives 20 binary outputs for each person*

Is it possible to prioritise certain **output** columns like giving weights or importance to certain columns more than others so that when we train the model it punishes incorrect predictions for these more important output columns more than others or would it make more sense to create separate models for these important columns?

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to use class weights with TensorFlow for this purpose. See the class_weight parameter for model.fit(): https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit